# Stackoverflow for huge xml

Tags: java, xml, web-services

In my web service when I am trying to run `XML` with huge content I'm getting below error .

Input is SOAP based web service . this error comes before any processing starts. server i am running my application is `weblogic 12.1.3.` Java version 1.7 .

I am not sure how to resolve this error as I need to enable my service to accept large `XML` content

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
        at com.sun.xml.stream.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanEntityReference(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1700)
        at com.sun.xml.stream.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2908)
        at com.sun.xml.stream.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2791)
        at com.sun.xml.stream.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2932)
        at com.sun.xml.stream.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2932)
        at com.sun.xml.stream.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2791)
        at com.sun.xml.stream.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2932)
        at com.sun.xml.stream.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2932)
        at com.sun.xml.stream.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2791)
        at com.sun.xml.stream.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2932)
        at com.sun.xml.stream.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2791)
        at com.sun.xml.stream.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2932)
        at com.sun.xml.stream.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2791)
        at com.sun.xml.stream.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2932)
        at com.sun.xml.stream.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2791)
        at com.sun.xml.stream.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2932)
        at com.sun.xml.stream.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2791)
        at com.sun.xml.stream.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2932)
        at com.sun.xml.stream.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2791)
        at com.sun.xml.stream.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2932)
```

Comment: What is in the XML that is so huge? Are there repetitive tags that can be removed to create a smaller XML? Will such a smaller XML run?

Comment: yes the small xml runs. content is correct . requirement is to process large xml data via webservice. upto a certain threshold server is able to accpet the request . beyond it , servers logs get filled with stackoverflow error

Comment: Have you tried increasing the max heap size of your JVM and tried running? Can you find out the exact threshold at which the xml becomes large enough to throw the error?

Comment: i tried increasing the size of Stack size per thread to 6M (-Xss) . it worked till the message content is of size 300k (characters) . however the message content can go beyond 300k and upto 500k . so increasing -Xss further is not an option for me

Comment: What version of Java 7? My jdk1.7.0_79 doesn't have `next()` calling itself at those lines (or anywhere), and there is a fixed bug regarding this: [JDK-2204370](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-2204370).

Comment: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_75-b13)

Comment: Can you show us the code?

Comment: It looks to me very much like the JDK bug identified by @Andreas

Comment: there was webservice-rt.jar added in the EAP lib . from there this class was being referred . i removed it and now that large xml is processed . however now i am getting below in case of Error Response
com.sun.xml.ws.spi.db.DatabindingException: Unknown JAXBContext implementation: class com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for the stackoverflow error: it was because of old webservice-rt.jar added in EAP lib. i looked into the stack trace in error and found those classes were from it. removed jars and it solved it. 
for unkonwn JAXBcontent  I tried looking for answer on various blogs but could not find the answer. then i decompiled jars and found out below which helped in resolving this error . Error was coming because of classes with different version in JDK and weblogic.

-Djavax.xml.bind.JAXBContext=com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory

Answer (score 0):

There are streaming-based XML parsers. You could utilize them, if you can manipulate the parsing in your web service (framework).

Take a look at [StAX](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/stax/).